# Confused by (char *) cast

Tags: c++, casting, ampersand

```
struct myStruct
{
  int foo;
}

myStruct bar;
bar.foo = 123;
cout<<(char *) &bar<<endl;
```

The cout statement prints out '{'. 
The ASCII of 123 is actually '{' (bar.foo = 123. Changing this value around prints out different characters). What I don't understand is that

```
cout<<(char *) &bar<<endl;
```

should technically print the address of bar. How am I able to access the data inside the structure using a (char *) cast? Using (int *) still returns the address. I do know that a (char *) causes data to be arranged in a byte-by-byte fashion, but shouldn't that just affect the address?

Comment: `std::cout` treats `char *` as null-terminated string and prints as such. `bar::foo` address is equal to `bar` address itself. So you print `bar::foo` as if it is a null-terminated string. Note, it'll print till `\0`, so it might go past `bar::foo`, depending on its value.

Comment: You're lucky that there is no crash, because it reads the memory till the first '\0'... There is no guarantee that you have one before accessing forbidden zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overload for `<<` taking `const char *`, which interprets the operand as a pointer to a C-style zero-terminated string. That's the overload used by, for example

```
cout << "Hello\n";
```

If, as here, you give it a pointer to something other than a C-style string, you'll get undefined behaviour. In practice, it will print the contents of memory byte by byte until it reaches a zero-valued byte or walks off the end of readable memory.

Comment: So if I were to send the cast over a socket, say char *bytes = (char *) &bar; write(socketFD, bytes, sizeof(myStruct)); It would work considering the byte-ordering is same on both ends?

Comment: @AamirKhan: Yes (assuming, as you say, compatible memory layout on both ends). But the cast is pointless: `write` takes a `const void*`, and `&bar` will convert implicitly if you do `write(fd, &bar, sizeof bar)`

Comment: As @MikeSeymour said. It depends on memory layout. If your intention is to support different platforms in the future, it's better to serialize the structure for network transport in well defined format. Integers are stored differently on different platforms, there are different alignment rules for structure members even across compilers. See for example htonl,htons functions for converting values between host and network odred.

Comment: "If, as here, you give it a pointer to something other than a C-style string", well, I reckon in this case it *was* given a pointer to a C-style string. But that depends on the implementation-defined layout of an `int` with value `123` -- on another implementation or with a different value it need not necessarily be a C-style string.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed; I didn't want to get bogged down in pedantic detail, but you're right that it is well-defined if the implementation-defined layout of whatever is in memory is a valid C-string in the implementation you're using. I'll keep my answer simple though - "undefined" is a good enough approximation unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` on a `char*` treats it as a C string, not a pointer. This program interprets a `myStruct` as a buffer of `sizeof(myStruct)` bytes and relies on the endianness to ensure that it's NUL-terminated.

To print the address, just pass `&bar` without a cast.

Comment: @Wolf: my point was that it might be cast to `void*` to print a pointer value, although that's not necessary here.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for the fuss.

Answer (score 1):

As bar is object of myStruct structure its starting address and the first member's starting address in myStruct ie bar.foo will be same. So &bar will give you starting address of bar object and char* will provide you value of first byte of in that address location.

Answer (score 1):

unlike `int *`, `char *` are special kind of pointers, they are also used to point to ASCII strings like such:

`const char * s = "hello world";`

For the expression `(char *) &bar` the result is a `char *` pointer, `cout` therefore will print a string because it has a special operator for `char *` that ouputs strings. for `int *` there is no operator, there is just a generic operator for pointers that prints just addresses.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ostream` typically has an overload for `operator <<` with `const char *` to which a `char *` will get bound to.

This overload treats its argument as a null-terminated string of ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to output contents of myStruct to output stream, you need to define ostream <<  operator for your structure like this:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const myStruct& ms) 
{
    os << "myStruct { foo: " << ms.foo << "\n}";
    return os; 
}
```

(char *) doesn't rearrange anything. The structure is stored in memory as 4 bytes = sizeof(int) or 8 bytes on 64bit CPU, depending on processor architecture in little-endian or big-endian layout (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Your code is probably running on x86 architecture CPU, so the least significant byte is stored at lower address. For example number 123 in foo will be stored as bytes 7B 00 00 00. In memory. Your cast co char * will tell compiler to use ostream operator for char * array which is used as string in C.  Each byte is interpreted as one character, terminated by 0 byte. Byte 123 corresponds to ASCII character '{', it's terminated by byte 00, so your code will not crash in this case. Other values may crash your code, or print bytes on stack beyond the storage of your structure (until zero byte is encountered, or crash).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is printing the address of struct variable bar not the value of foo.(char*)&bar is converting the address of struct type to (char*) means c string type.
Some c,c++,function parameters does take the struct type as arguments so we need to convert the struct type to (char*) or (void*) as per function parameters.